# Animation is moving with other object jquery

Tags: jquery

I have problem, that when I start animation for one object another is moving too.
So I need fixed div elements on left side.
I need set some z-index?

```
<div id="obsah">
    <div class="item colorBlue">
        <p>spousta textu</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item colorPurple">
        <p>spousta textu</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item colorGreen">
        <p>spousta textu</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item colorYellow">
        <p>spousta textu</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item colorRed">
        <p>spousta textu</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".item").click(function() {
        var div=$(this);
        div.animate({left:"110px",width:'600px'},"slow");
        div.animate({height:'600px'},"slow");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X6S3d/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `div` elements expand they are pushing the ones below them down. To stop this behaviour you need to use `position: absolute` on them, then set their `top` position manually. Something like this:

```
.item {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
.colorBlue {
    background-color: #33B5E5;
    top: 10px;
}
```

And so on for the other colour classes.

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/X6S3d/1/)

Comment: @user3671862 it's worth knowing that `position: absolute` is absolute to the closest ancestor that has `position: relative`, so if you need to position these divs in a particular part of the page, their parent can use `position: relative` to control that offset, rather than adding the height of a menu to top for example.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Nice utilization of `top`; tried with `br` http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/6wnmA/